# Two-way bind não funciona se o model for algo como ng-model=“record.name” para os Kendo UI controls

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Tenho um problema com o Kendo UI controls

meu HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="record.name" kendo-numeric-text-box />
 <input type="text" ng-model="record.name"> </input>
 <button ng-click="resetRecord()" >test bind</button>
```

meu test.js

```
$scope.record ={};
$scope.resetRecord= function(){
        $scope.record = {};
    }
```

Quando executo a função `resetRecord` somente o input padrão limpa o seu conteúdo, os input do Kendo UI não limpa, eu tentei `$scope.record =null` mas não funciona também.

Se eu mudar o código abaixo, ele funciona, mas eu preciso que ele funciona como acima.

```
$scope.resetRecord= function(){
        $scope.record. name = null;
    }
```

Isso acontece com todos os Kendo UI input, não somente com o kendo-numeric-text-box

Se existir uma maneira de interagir com o objecto  `record`, descobrindo todas as suas propriedades, como **name** dava certo pra mim.

Minha intenção é somente ter um controlador para todas as telas crud do sistema, eu não gostaria de escrever um controlador e a definição do modelo para cada entidade do sistema.

Será um bug?

Answer (score 1):

A solução é apenas adicionar o atributo `k-rebind`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="record.name" k-rebind="record.name" kendo-numeric-text-box />
```